# Heap Size vs HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS at namenode

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using hadoop apache 2.7.1 in HA Cluster.
I needed to update heap memory for both name nodes, so I updated 
the property HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS in hadoop-env.sh to be 8 gb

```
export HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS="-Xmx8192m $HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS"
```

so the heap size in my name nodes is now 8 GB

but I realized the parameter HADOOP_HEAPSIZE in hadoop-env.sh

and I didn't give it any value

is setting HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS to 8 GB enough or should we set HADOOP_HEAPSIZE to 8 GB too?

I mean does the value  HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS override the value HADOOP_HEAPSIZE
or should be both configured and each one has its specific job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does the value HADOOP_NAMENODE_OPTS overrides the value HADOOP_HEAPSIZE

Yes, it does. https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/admin_nn_memory_config.html

Comment: are Cloudera configurations are exact to hadoop apache 2.7.1?

Comment: For the most part, yes, Cloudera, Hortonworks, and MapR use the base Hadoop packages, but replace 2.7.1 with whatever version they support. The Hadoop daemons still operate the same... It is also mentioned here. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/ClusterSetup.html